# set Image(PNG etc) as an icon on drawer layout navigation items

Tags: java, android, android-menu, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I'm setting the image as icon but its showing grey icon not the image,

This `@drawable/image_second` is the image I want to use as icon.
[image: image_second.png]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/image_second"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="@string/menu_gallery" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="@string/menu_slideshow" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_tools"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="@string/menu_tools" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="@string/menu_share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_send"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="@string/menu_send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

after running the code,I get this,
[image]

please tell what to do and why its happening..

As always thanks a lot..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You can do so programmatically using
>   NavigationView.setItemIconTintList.

```
yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Also If you want to change the tint of other icons use this

**In XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ...
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/black" 
    ... />
```

Comment: @GOVIND_Dixit ..thanks a lot it worked..I had no idea about why this was happening...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the item icon tint.

```
mNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```